# Trying to center multiple images

Tags: html, css, image

This has been doing my head in xD, basically I'm trying to center my images, but the first image that gets referenced in for example imgTop seems to be the middle image and the other goes onto the right. Where I want to center both evenly. Thanks in advance

```css
#imageContainer {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.imgTop {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-left: 85pt;
  padding-right: 85pt;
}
.imgBottom {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-left: 85pt;
  padding-right: 85pt;
}
```

```html
<div id="imageContainer">
  <div class="imgTop">
    <a class="imageSlot">
      <img src="src/gameImages/img3.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="imgTop">
    <a class="imageSlot">
      <img src="src/gameImages/img4.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="imageContainer">
  <div class="imgBottom">
    <a class="imageSlot">
      <img src="src/gameImages/img4.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="imgBottom">
    <a class="imageSlot">
      <img src="src/gameImages/img3.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine - http://jsfiddle.net/jo7sv81m/ **Note*: you are using an ID more than once and that's not permitted so I swithced that to a class. Whether than is part of the issue *you* are seeing, I don't know.

Comment: If you can replicate the problem in a demo we might be able to help.

Comment: If the images are supposed to right next to each other...just remove the padding - http://jsfiddle.net/jo7sv81m/2/

Comment: I found my issue, it was the width and height that I set for my images under imageTop and imageBottom. But now I'm back to my old problem trying to make my images a certain size.

Comment: Ok...that would require a ***new*** question...but make sure you search SO carefully before posting (and if possible provide a demo). This WILL have come up before.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i got it right... but you want both picutres to be at the middle and not only one? So what i did is make 1 div tag out of 2 and position them together.

```
<div id="imageContainer">
        <div class="imgTop">
            <a class="imageSlot"><img src="http://zoarchurch.co.uk/content/pages/uploaded_images/91.png"></a>
            <a class="imageSlot"><img src="http://zoarchurch.co.uk/content/pages/uploaded_images/91.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="imageContainer">
        <div class="imgBottom">
            <a class="imageSlot"><img src="http://zoarchurch.co.uk/content/pages/uploaded_images/91.png"></a>
            <a class="imageSlot"><img src="http://zoarchurch.co.uk/content/pages/uploaded_images/91.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gswq55x2/